# Android Parsing a website with AsyncTask, urlConnection and InputStreamReader takes too long

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to parse the following page with AsyncTask, urlConnection and InputStreamReader

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    URL url;
    URLConnection urlConnection;
    String result = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

And I am using this on this way:

```
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    String data = null;
    try {

        data = downloadTask.execute("http://www.imdb.com/movies-in-theaters/").get();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is that it takes more than 3 mins to finish the DownloadTask. Finally after this time it works on the emulator but not in a real device.

**I know that this is not a good way** (parsing a web page) to do stuff like that, but I am doing it for educational reasons.

Any advice how I can speed up the procedure?

Thanks!

Comment: remove .get() from asynctask

Comment: Calling .get() on the `AsyncTask` makes the whole thing synchronous. Override `onPostExecute` to finish the work. Also, don't read one character at a time in the body of the task. Use a reasonably sized buffer calling `read(char[] cbuf, int offset, int length)`.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but making this asynchronous without the get(), will not affect the speed of the parsing but the code flow will return without waiting task to finish. This will lead me to NullPointerExceptions as the data that I am expecting to handle will be null. Using a value on the onPostExecute and continue only if this gets a value, down not make sense since we are "doing" asynchronous task synchronous.